# Тестирование и избавление от связности классов.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Добрый день! У меня есть приложение asp.net mvc. В нем я пытаюсь создавать архитектуру "по уму" - с Dependency Injection, тестами и тд. В приложении есть классы-сервис, в которых сосредоточена бизнес-логика. Мне необходимо покрыть эти сервисы тестами. Многие сервисы используют класс настроек, экземпляры которых им передаются в конструкторах. Например:

```
public class AppSettings  
{
    public AppSettings()
    {
        SomeStr =  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["str"]).ToString();  
        // и еще несколько подобных  строк         
    }

    public string SomeStr { get;set; }
}


public class MyService 
{
    public MyService(AppSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    private readonly AppSettings _settings;
}
```

Проблема тут вот какая. В конструкторе класса `AppSettings` происходит инициализация неких переменных, данные о которых получаются из файла web.config. В коде самого приложения это работает, а вот если я пытаюсь тестировать класс `MyService` в отдельном тестовом приложении, то возникает проблема: классу нужно передавать экземпляр `AppSettings`, но при его создании  вываливается исключение из-за невозможности обратиться к `web.config`. Кроме того сами классы я напрямую не создаю, этим занимается DI-библиотека. Как быть в данном случае и как нормально протестировать `MyService`? К тому же мне кажется проблемой то, что в конструкторе класса `AppSettings` происходит обращение к `web.config. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: а если параметр из `web.config` передать как параметр необходимый для создания экземпляра класса? т.е. что то типа `public appSettings(string someStr){this.SomeStr = someStr;}`

Comment: @Bald но как это "рассказать" библиотеке DI, которая создает экземпляры классов?

Comment: ну так в `di контейнере` получайте нужное значение из конфига.

Comment: @Pupkin если для `Ninject`, то `kernel.Bind<IAppSetting>().To<AppSetting>() .WithConstructorArgument(someStr, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["str"]).ToString());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы используете класс `AppSettings` как класс настроек и `IoC-контейнер`, то опишите интерфейс `IAppSettings` и протестируйте с помощью `Mock` объектов.

Приведу пример. В классе `MyService` вы заменяете тип аргумента конструктора `settings` на `IAppSetting`. В `IoC-контейнере` регистрируете реализацию. Предположим, что вы используете `Ninject`, тогда `kernel.Bind<IAppSetting>().To<AppSetting>()`. Тогда в методе тестирования вы можете настроить свой объект.

```
Mock<IAppSetting>() mock = new Mock<IAppSetting>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Field1).Returns(value1);
MyService service = new MyService(mock.Object);
```

Здесь вы задаете, что при запрашивании `Field1` должно вернуться значение `value1`.

**Внимание** поле `Field1` должно быть определено в интерфейсе `IAppSetting`

---

**Пример показан для**  `Ninject`